# Stop a currently running writeToFile:

Tags: cocoa

I have some code which writes some `PDFDocument` objects to a user-chosen destination. This works fine.

Perhaps some of these files (chosen by the user) may be pretty large (maybe hundreds of megabytes) and now I wonder whether there is a possibility to cancel the current `writeToFile:withOptions:` call (e.g. the user changed his mind and wants to stop it).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do it with that method, since it provides no canceling functionality.

I suggest you use the `dataRepresentation` method of `PDFDocument` to first get the PDF data. You can then split up the data using `NSData`’s `subdataWithRange:`. And then you can successively write out the data to a file using `NSFileHandle`’s `fileHandleForWritingToURL:error:`, `writeData:`, and `closeFile` methods.

Writing it out in chunks like this from a non-main thread, in a `for`-loop say, you can cancel it any time you wish.

Comment: Usually this would be a way to do this. But unfortunately I'm using the `options` dictionary to provide a Quartz filter which causes the PDF file to be compressed.